# Monitor SELECT statements with ETW and EVENT SESSION

Tags: sql-server-2008, etw

I am currently working with ETW on SQL Server 2008 to monitor (and eventually log) SQL statement execution. The events that I am looking to monitor are stored proc execution, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and... SELECT statements.

I am able to monitor the SPs, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE by creating an EVENT SESSION with the following events:

- sqlserver.sp_statement_completed
- sqlserver.sp_statement_starting
- sqlserver.sql_statement_completed
- sqlserver.sql_statement_starting

I also include an action with each event to add the actual SQL statement to the event: sqlserver.sql_text

My session basically looks something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION SomeTestEventSession ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed (ACTION (sqlserver.sql_text) WHERE sqlserver.database_id > 4),
(...)
```

What **event** should I add to the ones above to monitor simple **SELECT statements** on my database? I am aware this will create a lot of activity, but once I can monitor the statements, I will try to fine tune the beast by adding some filtering actions to reduce the actual number of logged events.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All, I must have overlooked something, because it seems the sql_statement_completed **does** monitor the SELECT statements.